# How can I prevent an api call to a port on my machine from logging me out of my django app?

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I have a pair of django apps. One runs an api on one port (8001) and the other app runs a website (port 8000) where angularJS on the page consumes that api generated by the other app. There are reasons I've set it up this way.

The apps don't share a user model.

When I log in to the website and go to the page with the AngularJS, I am logged out when I refresh the page.

I can disable 'AuthenticationMiddleware' and 'SessionAuthenticationMiddleware' on the api app, but then I can't log in to the admin panel. It's functional, but it's a non-starter.

My workaround of last resort is to stand up an admin only site that has authentication and uses the same db but doesn't have a publicly available API.

Surely there is a way to disable the Auth and SessionAuth middleware on a per view basis...

The app is built using the Django Rest Framework.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Make api server to use DRF [token based authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).

And to disable the Auth and SessionAuth middleware on a per view basis you will have to write custom middleware or decorator.

Comment: Django Rest Framework doesn't appear to be causing the problem. Opening the permissions completely still causes the error. I think my only choice is to disable Auth and SessionAuth on a per view basis.